# grub2-install error - disk not found

Tags: linux, boot, grub2

I've a CentOS 7 server that isn't booting anymore, ends in grub rescue with following error:

`` error: disk `mduuid/7d1ea14d586da4ea38a163ecc38fa93f' not found. ``

I've booted into systemrescue ISO, mounted the RAID array, chrooted to the array, and tried to install the grub via grub2-install on both disks, sda and sdb, both returning the same error:

```
    [root@sysrescue /]# grub2-install /dev/sda
    Installing for i386-pc platform.
    grub2-install: error: disk `mduuid/7d1ea14d586da4ea38a163ecc38fa93f' not found.
```

The RAID10 array looks as below:

```
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.0
     Creation Time : Wed Jan 25 15:15:48 2017
        Raid Level : raid10
        Array Size : 1953520640 (1863.02 GiB 2000.41 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976760320 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Wed Dec 30 18:11:18 2020
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 2
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : near=2
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : pilot.one:root  (local to host hv.christine)
              UUID : 7d1ea14d:586da4ea:38a163ec:c38fa93f
            Events : 2428023

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       17        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb1
       -       0        0        2      removed
       3       8       49        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sda1
```

I can't figure out why it keeps complaining about that md uuid and most importantly - how to resolve it. Could it be grub2 bug? The data on that array is all fine, I'm running RAID10 in degraded mode with 2 disks removed out of 4 total.

If I remember good, I had similar issue last time on other server and booting into rescue ISO, mounting the RAID array and running grub2-install on the /dev/sda was all what I needed to fix the problem, not this time it seems. Any help appreciated.