# grub2-install throws various errors instead of installing, how to proceed?

Tags: centos, grub2, mdadm, software-raid

The system is CentOS 7. It was installed on two hard disks with MD RAID, one drives died. We decided to switch to two SSDs of just marginally larger size. When they were connected and system was booted, `sda` apeared to be an old hard disk with two partitions, `sda1` participates in `md126` of 500M which is `/boot`, and `sda2` participates in `md127` which is the LVM PV which holds everything else. `sdb` and `sdc` are new SSDs.

I began moving arrays from hard drive to SSDs. I partitioned the new devices like the old ones, and added them into arrays, then arrays were grown to contain 3 devices:

```
mdadm --add /dev/md126 /dev/sd[bc]1
mdadm --add /dev/md127 /dev/sd[bc]2
mdadm --grow -n 3 /dev/md126
mdadm --grow -n 3 /dev/md127
```

After some time passed, I verified all RAIDs were fully synched, then I removed hard disk from arrays and set them back to contain 2 devices each:

```
mdadm -f /dev/md126 /dev/sda1
mdadm -r /dev/md126 /dev/sda1
mdadm -f /dev/md127 /dev/sda2
mdadm -r /dev/md127 /dev/sda2
mdadm --grow -n 2 /dev/md126
mdadm --grow -n 2 /dev/md127
```

Both arrays are clean. I went to installing the bootloader into newly installed devices:

```
[root@master ~]# grub2-install /dev/sdc
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub2-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume `(null)'. Some modules may be missing from core image..
grub2-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume `(null)'. Some modules may be missing from core image..
grub2-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume `(null)'. Some modules may be missing from core image..
grub2-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume `(null)'. Some modules may be missing from core image..
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

I wasn't very happy seeing these warnings, and I am still unsure it was installed to correct devices. I checked `/boot/grub2/device.map`, it referred to old drives, so I fixed it, now it is:

```
# this device map was generated by anaconda
(hd0)      /dev/sdb
(hd1)      /dev/sdc
(hd2)      /dev/sda
```

The leftover drive will be eventually removed and hopefully reused, so I was to clean it from any data (to not to leak it):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=8k
```

It finished, then I tried again reinstall grub onto SSDs, just to be sure:

```
[root@master ~]# grub2-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub2-install: error: disk `mduuid/85faee0a366da795c6ac33a7c4a48ae8' not found.
```

The first line appeared instantly, the error message was delayed by 10 seconds. The same for the second SSD.

If I make the `/dev/sda1` again and add it into array properly growing it to 3 devices, it shows instead:

```
[root@master /]# grub2-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub2-install: error: unknown filesystem.
```

I am sure it contains a valid boot file system. I separated it from the RAID and checked, it is there:

```
[root@master /]# blkid -p /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: UUID="85faee0a-366d-a795-c6ac-33a7c4a48ae8" UUID_SUB="bc7af7ca-09f2-f533-3a79-53d98f5dd09a" LABEL="master.service.intrid.ru:boot" VERSION="1.0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" USAGE="raid" PART_ENTRY_SCHEME="dos" PART_ENTRY_TYPE="0xfd" PART_ENTRY_FLAGS="0x80" PART_ENTRY_NUMBER="1" PART_ENTRY_OFFSET="2048" PART_ENTRY_SIZE="1046528" PART_ENTRY_DISK="8:0" 
[root@master /]# tune2fs -l /dev/md126 | grep feat
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
[root@master /]# mdadm -f /dev/md126 /dev/sda1
mdadm: set /dev/sda1 faulty in /dev/md126
[root@master /]# mdadm -r /dev/md126 /dev/sda1
mdadm: hot removed /dev/sda1 from /dev/md126
[root@master /]# tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep feat
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
```

Very strange.

Now I'm stuck. The system works fine, all filesystems are fine, it serves clients. For example, `/boot` is mounted and is available, I unmounted and checked it, then remounted back.

The Internet is filled with suggestions to reboot the system from the rescue live media, or even how to fix this after the grub was dropped into rescue shell on reboot. Some of resources I checked:

- https://ahelpme.com/linux/grub2-grub-install-error-disk-mduuid-not-found-even-after-the-partition-has-bios_grub-on/
- [grub2-install error - disk not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626905/grub2-install-error-disk-not-found) (which is not answered, by the way)
- https://linoxide.com/fix-grub-filesystem-type-unknown-error-on-centosredhat/
- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/centos-7-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue-4175687414/

However, I didn't rebooted it yet, and I don't want to, until I am sure it will boot, because it is remote, and the people around won't be able to fix bootloader. I replaced devices like this several times before, I don't remember such problems, however this was always done with Gentoo or Debian who usually have more recent software than CentOS.

So, is it possible to fix bootloader from the system, remotely, without booting rescue media? Probably, by telling grub to not to check anything and just write the required things into appropriate places on the media?

Will it help if I dump a `/boot` file system, recreate the array containing it from scratch and write the image back? How do I recreate initramfs afterwards?

Comment: Do not know Centos, but with Ubuntu BIOS version of grub renumbers where to install. #To see what drive grub2 uses see this line   - grub-pc/install_devices:
`sudo debconf-show grub-pc` # for BIOS with grub-pc  to see similar drive info
`sudo lshw -C Disk -short ` Do not know then if Centos uses same or similar info. This may update that info.  #to get grub2 to remember where to reinstall on major updates
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`  With UEFI installs the drive is remembered by entry in fstab.

Comment: This is BIOS (no EFI) install; also this is *already* grub2. And, again, I never had problems like this with other distros.

Comment: But do you have `sudo debconf-show grub-pc` or whatever equivalent is in Centos? My UEFI Ubuntu installs showed that output, and used to not show a drive at all. But now it shows both grub-efi/install_devices: with an entry and grub-pc/install_devices: as blank entry (since no grub-pc)

Comment: This is precisely what I am asking: how to do the equivalent in the CentOS. However, I don't remember running `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc1` or anything like this in Debian was required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time trying and thinking, I reverted to the first article I mentioned in the question: https://ahelpme.com/linux/grub2-grub-install-error-disk-mduuid-not-found-even-after-the-partition-has-bios_grub-on/

The author thinks there are some structures about array in the kernel which get rebuilt after reboot. At which moment, precisely? Likely during discovery and assembly. And true, **the reassembly of the boot array** helped. This is how I resolved this.

First we unmount and disassemble the array:

```
[root@master ~]# umount /boot
[root@master ~]# mdadm --stop /dev/md126
mdadm: stopped /dev/md126
[root@master ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] 
md127 : active raid1 sdc2[4] sdb2[3]
      487731200 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 2/4 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

`mdstat` showed no boot array, also I did read `dmesg` at this point to be certain everything went correct:

```
[243050.619210] md126: detected capacity change from 535756800 to 0
[243050.619260] md: md126 stopped.
[243050.619271] md: unbind<sdb1>
[243050.629871] md: export_rdev(sdb1)
[243050.630093] md: unbind<sdc1>
[243050.635890] md: export_rdev(sdc1)
```

Then reassembling it back:

```
[root@master ~]# mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md126 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
mdadm: /dev/md126 has been started with 2 drives.
```

Notice it auto-mounted itself, `dmesg` is:

```
[243124.197117] md: bind<sdc1>
[243124.197468] md: bind<sdb1>
[243124.200993] md/raid1:md126: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
[243124.201010] md126: detected capacity change from 0 to 535756800
[243124.201461]  md126: unknown partition table
[243124.238232]  md126: unknown partition table
[243124.246330] EXT4-fs (md126): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Now it was installed just fine:

```
[root@master ~]# LANG=C grub2-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
[root@master ~]# LANG=C grub2-install /dev/sdc
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

Without reboot!